# Use .Substring command for an array?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently writing some code which is supposed to read a file and put every line in an array (That works) and then use the `.Substring` command to split every line from the array into two variables (ID and NAME).

I think that the way I am doing could work but I always get the error - `The ID varible is being used before having a value`

```
'Puts every line from file in array
Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(cleanfile)

Dim ID As String()
Dim NAME As String()

'Supposed to substring every line and split it in ID and NAME 
'( ID(1) from lines(1), ID(2) from lines(2), etc. )
'Error starts here for ID and NAME
ID(1 - 40) = lines(1 - 40).Substring(0, 7)
NAME(1 - 40) = lines(1 - 40).Substring(30, 60)
```

What am I missing? Or is there some error in the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't index an array range the way you seem to be trying to. When you write `lines(1 - 40)`, it's not doing "lines one to forty" - it's doing "line minus thirty-nine."

Your error occurs for similar reason: you appear to be trying to create and set array values "one to forty," but really this is trying to set "value minus thirty-nine." Since you haven't *set* `ID` to anything yet, you can't do that: there's no array!

Really what you need is a loop, that will take each line in turn and process it. Fortunately, with Linq, the loop is abstracted away and the code can be more simple. 
The simplest way would be something like this:

```
Dim ID as String()

ID = lines.Select(Function (l as String) As String
                      return l.SubString(0, 7)
                  End Function).ToArray()
```